# Android Widget without having to use any broadcast receiver

Tags: android-widget, android

Is there a way to implement an android widget without having to use any broadcast receiver?

I know that the class has to extend the `AppWidgetProvider` class (which extends broadcast receiver). But I am looking for a way around without having to extend the `AppWidgetProvider` and registering the class as the receiver in the xml file. Or is there a way I can make a UI that can know if an android application is running(Again, no broadcasting)?

Answer (score 0):

> But I am looking for a way around without having to extend the AppWidgetProvider and registering the class as the receiver in the xml file.

You definitely need the `<receiver>` and its associated app widget metadata in the manifest -- that's unavoidable. In theory, you are welcome to have the receiver be a no-op (i.e., drop all received broadcasts) and update the app widget yourself via `AppWidgetManager` elsewhere in your code. However, I suspect that your user experience may suck at the time the user adds the app widget to their home screen, as Android will be expecting your `AppWidgetProvider` to update the app widget UI, and if it doesn't, you might get unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I want to implement a very simple widget with a refresh button that will query an application to check if the application is running and the requirement is that no broadcast receivers must be used. It would be great if you could guide me on how to go about it.

If not widget a UI to check if the application is running.

Thanks.

Comment: @user3780902: "the requirement is that no broadcast receivers must be used" -- that is not possibly, sorry. "a UI to check if the application is running" -- use `ActivityManager`.